# Latest Tesseract in Tika

Tags: tesseract, python-tesseract, apache-tika, tika-server, tika-python

Newest available version of Tesseract is 5.x. but the latest tika is still using 4.x.
Is it possible to upgrade version of tesseractOCR in Tika?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We kept the 1.x branch alive for a year after cutting over to 2.x to
allow people time to migrate.  Most of the changes in 1.x in the last
6 months or so have been security related.  We will no longer support
1.x after September 30, 2022.

I've opened a ticket and PR to upgrade tesseract to 5.x in our next 2.x release -- 2.5.0.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-3860